# Replacing image extensions in jQuery, go from .png to .gif on the fly

Tags: jquery, replace, png, css, gif

So, I'm using CSS3 in order to create sidebar boxes in my site design, this works nice and dandy. Using http://css3pie.com in order to create the effect in IE.

Again, nice and dandy. Now, comes my issue -

For each relatively positioned module, there is an absolutely positioned icon within it, that is set to being top: -20px in order to give it a pop-out effect. Obviously this doesn't work in IE6, as well it doesn't play nice with any PNG fix codes.

However, for IE6 users I can switch to a low-quality gif instead, and they can deal with it.

Now, my question is, how can I manage to live-switch image.png to image.gif if the user is using IE6?

I have yet to find a reasonable solution for this idea. I could use an IE6 stylesheet to replace the images - however there are several instances where images shouldn't be CSS-based. They should be proper images.

Any suggestions? I wanted some sort of a jQuery replace, but I haven't found a reasonable solution for that either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several solutions. Probably the easiest would be to create a jQuery function that was called when the user switches to the low-fi site (by link) or you determine this on their behalf (by headers or conditional comment).

The jQuery function could utilize attribute selectors to make life easier.

```
function switch_to_low_fi() {
        $('img[src$=".png"]').each(function(index,element) {
          element.src = element.src.replace('.png','.gif');
        });
}
```

To switch the CSS backgrounds, I would recommend classing them with `degrade` or something of the sort to create a hook for jQuery, then doing something similar as the above.

```
        $('.degrade').each(function(index,element) {
          element = $(element);
          var background = element.css('background-image');
          background = background.replace('.png','.gif');
          element.css('background-image', background);
        });
```

Of course, you will need to modify the code above base on your markup, but that should get you started.

Comment: `element` is a bare DOM object so you'll need to do `$(element).css('background-image');` Good use of attribute selectors though.

Comment: you missed the one on line 2 :)

Comment: what if during replace('.png','.gif')  you accidentaly replace filename or even worse, some other part of url (e.g. domain)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all non-CSS images on the page:

```
// when DOM is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // and browser is MSIE 6 or lower
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version <= 6) {
        // go through every IMG
        jQuery('img').each(function(index,element){
            // if there's a .png in the source, I'll assume it's at the end
            // (of course, more complex test could be made) ...
            if (element.src.indexOf('.png') != -1) {
                // ...and replace it with a GIF version
                element.src = element.src.replace('.png','.gif'); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This will work, but a conditional comment is better than `if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version <= 6)`

Comment: @Josh Stodola: Good point. Do JScript conditional comments have a facility for testing the browser version, or do you have to check for the version manually?

Comment: Yes you can, that is their main purpose.  Only recognized by IE though; not a standard.  More info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: @Josh Stodola: I was thinking of JavaScript CC: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml , but HTML CCs would work, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this PHP code in the CSS to know what browser is being used:

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’]);
if (preg_match(‘|MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|’,$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = ‘IE’;
    echo ... ;//css selector for Internet Explorer and so on...
} elseif (preg_match( ‘|Opera ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|’,$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = ‘Opera’;
} elseif(preg_match(‘|Firefox/([0-9\.]+)|’,$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = ‘Firefox’;
} elseif(preg_match(‘|Safari/([0-9\.]+)|’,$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = ‘Safari’;
} else {
// browser not recognized!
$browser_version = 0;
$browser= ‘other’;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how to replace the elements or how to get the browser/version?

jQuery has facilities for both.

Getting the browser is straightforward. just use `jQuery.browser`.

To change the images would require a different approach for CSS vs. `<img>`. Set everything to use PNG's and then do something like:

```
if ( useGIF() ) {
    var src;
    $('img').each(function() {
        src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-3) + 'gif');
    };
    $('.has_bg_png').each(function() {
        src = $(this).css('background-image');
        $(this).css('background-image', src.substr(0, src.length-3) + 'gif');
    };
}
```